# Convert PostgreSQL dump to Oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, pg-dump

Can we convert PostgreSQL (database and dump) to Oracle without lose information and without using another application from the Internet?

Comment: Depends on how you took the dump. Have at it with an editor!

Comment: It will also depend on just what kind of objects are in your dump, and whether the SQL produced is 100% compatible with the version of Oracle you are moving to. The more custom things that are in your database, the more difficult the migration could be.

Comment: How should I take the dump to migrate it to Oracle? Can you give me the example with any editor, please

Comment: Maybe we can convert `pg_dump database > database.sql` and insert `database.sql` to Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should export PostgreSQL database in plain SQL format with something like:

```
pg_dump --column-insert database > database.sql
```

and adapt the generated SQL file to Oracle.